# Is there anyway to automatically add faces messages when logging?

Tags: java, log4j, jsf-2, java-ee-6

```
 if (event.getDate().compareTo(startDate) < 0) {

        logger.warn(message.getValue("dateWarnMsg"));
        FacesUtils.addWarnMessage(message.getValue("dateWarnMsg"));
    }
```

I have a lot of code like this.  Is there a way after a log to automatically add a faces message?

Something like this?

```
 if (event.getDate().compareTo(startDate) < 0) {

        logger.warn(message.getValue("dateWarnMsg"), addFacesMessage);

    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding another method to `FacesUtils`? Or wrapping it inside another class if `FacesUtils` isn't part of your classes. Something like:

```
addWarnMessageAndLog(String warningMessage) {
   logger.warn(warningMessage);
   FacesUtils.addWarnMessage(warningMessage);
}
```

Using interceptors or some other form of aspect oriented programming might also help you if you don't like this route.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Interceptors for that. Read more [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/interceptor/AroundInvoke.html).